# SQL Server Tuning: Database Engine Tuning Advisor

Tags: sql-server

I have a very amateurish question, so please don't bomb me. I work in a small company where I serve the role of everything from developer to DBA. We have an MSSQL 2008 database, of which one of the tables is experiencing some very slow access for SELECT operations. In trying to research how to deal with this, I was suggested to run the Database Engine Tuning Advisor. The report generated tells me I can have a improvement of 99% by creating a few indexes and statistics. Is it safe to just go ahead and run all these generated queries? Has anyone worked with the Database Engine Tuning Advisor enough to tell me if it is reliable? I frankly don't have the experience to analyze this problem on my own, so I feel like relying completely on the tool is a bit ridiculous. At the same time, I am under pressure to do something to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DTA is very good when it has sufficient work load to operate on.
However, for 1 or 2 Odd queries, DTA can't suggest you very good solutions.
I suggest, Review the indexes suggested and check if they need to be created.
Do not create all indexes suggested as it may have adverse effect on the overall system.
I believe if your select queries are very slow, then it should be duw to missing index on the columns in your where clause. Choose the best option from DTA, review it and then create your indexes and stats as required.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By sufficient workload you mean how long I run the analysis for? I have decided to run a trace overnight to get a full 24 hours worth of data, then use this for analysis. Do you think it's enough?

Comment: It really depends on thw worload and how much part of your application is being used in the time frame. Do you feel a good part of your system is covered in the 24 hours?